# PyFoam problem - ImportError: No module named PyFoam

Tags: python, numpy, installation, openfoam, cfdata

I just install PyFoam using:

```
pip install PyFoam
```

Then I wrote a test.py file using:

```
import PyFoam
```

Now I got an error message:

```
    import PyFoam
ImportError: No module named PyFoam
```

Then I tried install again, and I got this:

```
pip install PyFoam
Requirement already satisfied: PyFoam in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (2021.6)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from PyFoam) (1.23.0)
```

Could anyone help? Tks.

Comment: Sounds like a common virtual-env issue. How are you running your `test.py`?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is likely that you use one version of pip and another version of the Python interpreter. This is particularly common if you have several Python installations on your system. Check that these versions match with each other.

For example, run

```
python --version
pip --verion
```

You should see output similar to the following:

```
Python 3.10.2
pip 22.1.2 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)
```

Notice the matching version numbers. I am verifying this on my system with Homebrew, under MacOS, but I assume that it's similar on other systems. Here, different instances of "python" and "pip" binaries are suffixed with the version number. So, if your version of "pip" says "3.8", try specifying "python3.8" as interpreter.

It might also be helpful for troubleshooting to know of the "-m" switch, in order to locate a module. In your example, you would run:

```
python -mPyFoam
```

Notice the capitalization for this module, which can differ between the one being used to install the module through pip and when importing it. On my system, as an example, it outputs:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3: No module named PyFoam.__main__; 'PyFoam' is a package and cannot be directly executed
```

The error message is fine. It does still mean the module was found. That is in contrast to an output like the following:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3: No module named pyfoam
```

The -m switch is documented under https://peps.python.org/pep-0338/.

Another possibility might be that you need to check and configure your Python module search path, as described here https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html.

> When a module named spam is imported, the interpreter first searches
> for a built-in module with that name. These module names are listed in
> sys.builtin_module_names. If not found, it then searches for a file
> named spam.py in a list of directories given by the variable sys.path.
> sys.path is initialized from these locations:
>
> The directory containing the input script (or the current directory
> when no file is specified).
>
> PYTHONPATH (a list of directory names, with the same syntax as the
> shell variable PATH).
>
> The installation-dependent default (by convention including a
> site-packages directory, handled by the site module).
>
> Note On file systems which support symlinks, the directory containing
> the input script is calculated after the symlink is followed. In other
> words the directory containing the symlink is not added to the module
> search path. After initialization, Python programs can modify
> sys.path. The directory containing the script being run is placed at
> the beginning of the search path, ahead of the standard library path.
> This means that scripts in that directory will be loaded instead of
> modules of the same name in the library directory. This is an error
> unless the replacement is intended. See section Standard Modules for
> more information.

It's possible to try to think of other causes. But without any additional information about your setup it would probably be too speculative and become confusing for other people reading this answer, so I will leave it at these two causes, which I believe to be the most common for this type of issue.

Comment: You are right:
`python --version
Python 2.7.18
PyFoam pip --version
pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)`

Although, the other command doens't work properly: `python -mPyFoam
/usr/bin/python: No module named PyFoam`
It's not clear how to solve it.

Comment: I apologize that it's not clear what my proposed solution is. I tried to write it clearly. The suggestion was to invoke your script with the command "python3.8 test.py" (without the quotes) explicitly.

Comment: Tks. It worked as python3 test.py. Although, when I try to use the pyFoam with my OpenFoam case I got this message error `  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 786, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'PyFoam==2021.6' distribution was not found and is required by the application
`

Comment: Then you might want to go the other way and change the instance of pip you use, such as "pip2.7 install pyfoam" or "pip2 install pyfoam", since whatever method you use to run your code appears to insist on a Python2.7 environment.